# URL for map with marker for iOS and Google?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, apple-maps

I've been reading https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1

I'm trying to simply have a `URL` that opens a map with a marker for given `GPS` coordinates that works for both `Apple` and `Android/PC`.

```
Maps.apple.com?ll=‎40.748817,‎-73.985428‎&q=abc
```

**When the link is clicked on `iOS`, it opens a map at the location with a pin titled 'abc'.**

**If clicked on an android or PC it centres the map but doesn't show a pin.**

Does anyone know how to have a single `URL` that will give a marker on all platforms?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Please check [static google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro). It provides image url of map with given zoom level and pin. Working fine in android and ios. Since it is image url, it should work fine in all platform. Load this via image loader like Picasso.

Comment: Thank you that is 90% OK for our application. The only thing is we want the user to be able to use their native map application so they can move the marker if need be and get its latitude and longitude numbers. Maybe I'll have to programmatically try and find out if they are using Apple OSX or iOS and then use an Apple Maps link else use a Google Maps link.